# Can Dart consume WCF services?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, dart

Can Dart consume WCF services? If so, how?

More broadly, how can one go from a "Javascript <--> ASP.NET <--> WCF Service <--> SQL" web app to one with a Dart front-end?

Comment: This isnt a sql question. This is a wcf/dart question

Comment: Search the web for "dart consume web service" and try some libraries that let you perform REST or SOAP calls.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its doable - at least in debug mode. I struggled a bit with it to say the least. I hope other people can benefit from it.

To make it work with dart you need to place the dart project in a sub folder beneath your solution folder and include the (dart)files in your Visual Studio project.

Gotcha: 
The function I have invoked is string from Darts viewpoint, but .NET must consume a stream. I hope someone can show a better solution.

So I have this in my ICalculationService. I hope someone can shed some light on why it has to be this way:

```
            [OperationContract]
            System.IO.Stream RunCalculation(System.IO.Stream calculation);
```

The dart code is simple (and programmers do appreciate simplicity)

```
            void runCalculation() {
              String url = "http://localhost:5548/CalculationService.svc/RunCalculation";
              String data = "raw stuff to send to the service";
              Future<HttpRequest> request = HttpRequest.request(url, method: 'POST',sendData: data );
              request.then((HttpRequest resp) {
                DivElement div = querySelector("#someresult_div");
                div.text = resp.responseText;
              });
            }
```

Here is a working web config (project is a WCF service application):

```
            <?xml version="1.0"?>
            <configuration>
              <appSettings/>
              <system.web>
                <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
                <httpRuntime/>
              </system.web>
              <system.serviceModel>
                <behaviors>
                  <endpointBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="YourDefaultNamespace.CalculationService">
                      <enableWebScript/>
                    </behavior>
                  </endpointBehaviors>
                  <serviceBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="debug">
                      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    </behavior>
                    <behavior>
                      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                    </behavior>
                  </serviceBehaviors>
                </behaviors>
                <protocolMapping>
                  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
                </protocolMapping>
                <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
                <services>
                  <service name="YourDefaultNamespace.CalculationService" behaviorConfiguration="debug">
                    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="YourDefaultNamespace.CalculationService" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="YourDefaultNamespace.ICalculationService"/>
                    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"/>
                  </service>
                </services>
              </system.serviceModel>
              <system.webServer>
                <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
                <!--
                    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
                    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
                  -->
                <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
                <staticContent>
                  <remove fileExtension=".dart"/>
                  <mimeMap fileExtension=".dart" mimeType="text/x.dart"/>
                </staticContent>
              </system.webServer>
            </configuration>
```

If you want to do stuff in pure javascript this might help to understand what goes on in the obscure wcf/asp.net world: [http://kinsey.no/blog/index.php/2009/10/28/using-wcfsvcs-automatically-generated-javascript-proxies-*without*-asp-net-ajax/](http://kinsey.no/blog/index.php/2009/10/28/using-wcfsvcs-automatically-generated-javascript-proxies-_without_-asp-net-ajax/)

Comment: Any idear how to deal with server-side required client-certificates?